# ArcGIS pythonaddins.ProgressDialog inconsistent progress bar drawing

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to use `pythonaddins.ProgressDialog` in a Python add-in. I am on ArcGIS 10.4.

I will need to perform several steps that will take some time. To show how much work is done, I plan to use a progress bar which is available with the  [`pythonaddins.ProgressDialog`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm).

Trying to run this sample code in the Python window in ArcMap (taken from the [Esri help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm)):

```
import pythonaddins
with pythonaddins.ProgressDialog as dialog:
    dialog.title = "Progress Dialog"
    dialog.description = "Copying a large feature class."
    dialog.animation = "File"
    for i in xrange(100):
        dialog.progress = i
        time.sleep(0.125)
        if dialog.cancelled:
            raise Exception("Ooops")
```

The code works fine unless you increase the step in the `xrange()` from 1 to something bigger. For instance, if you have 10 feature class to copy, it would make sense to make a step of 10 units (100 / 10) so every increase in the bar would correspond to a copied item.

However, I am observing inconsistent drawing of the progress bar. Try running this code in Python window in ArcMap, in a Python add-in or in a script tool.

```
with pythonaddins.ProgressDialog as dialog:
    dialog.title = "Progress Dialog"
    dialog.description = "Copying a large feature class."
    dialog.animation = "File"    
    for i in xrange(0,100,10):
        dialog.progress = i
        time.sleep(0.5)        
        if dialog.cancelled:
            raise Exception("Ooops")
```

This is how it looks on my machine. As you can see, the progress bar is jumping back and forth. I've tried multiple steps (2,5,10,20) and observed the same behavior: as long as the step is not 1, the bar jumps back and forth in progress.

[image]

Has anyone seen this and know if there is any workaround for this?

Comment: @PolyGeo, out of curiosity, why did you remove the `arcgis-desktop` and `python` tags? I do run Python code inside ArcGIS Desktop, makes sense to me. `arcpy` tag you've added, on the other hand, I don't use at all.

Comment: Technically the `pythonaddins` module falls outside the ArcPy site package but to try to keep the tagging scheme simple I group them together for tagging purposes.  That way those who are only able to answer ArcGIS GUI questions just filter for [tag:arcgis-desktop] and those able to answer ArcGIS (Python) coding questions just filter for [tag:arcpy].  I see it as a pragmatic rather than purist approach.